# Magento Sales order Database Tables out of sync

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a problem with the sales_flat_order_payment table in Magento, the entity_id and parent_id have become out of sync. For example the entity_id reads 48058 and the corresponding parent_id reads 48059. It is my understanding these should read the same. This happened overnight and I can look back into the Database and see that two orders were never created in the sales_flat_order table and sales_flat_order_grid table, after that the sales_flat_order_payment table became out of sync so I guess some issue happened under heavy load. How can I correct this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In sales_flat_order_payment table:

- entity_id is 'payment id' (just auto increment).
- parent_id is 'order id' (entity_id column in sales_flat_order table).

Here is no error - some orders don't have payments whats why it's not synced and 'parent_id' increment > 'entity_id' increment.